# Prob in publishing post on aggregation view

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

I have created a timeline app with local IP, the status of my app is "Pending".

It's working for the account where I have created this app but when I am trying to submit/publish the message on a different user's wall I am getting this error message "(#200) Requires extended permission: publish_actions or App must be on whitelist".
I have already defined permission for "publish_actions":

```
$loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
        array(
            'display'   => 'popup',
            'next'      => $fbconfig['baseurl'] . '?loginsucc=1',
            'cancel_url'=> $fbconfig['baseurl'] . '?cancel=1',
            'scope'     => 'publish_checkins,publish_actions, email, offline_access, read_stream, publish_stream, user_birthday, user_location, user_work_history, user_about_me, user_hometown',       
            'redirect_uri'  => $fbconfig['baseurl']
        )
);
```

I have used php sdk for this, code mentioned below:

```
$publishStream = $facebook->api('/$user/recommendurl:recommend', 
                            'post', array(
                'website' => 'http://www.shopakira.com/',
                'place'   => '108424279189115',
                'message' => "Test recommendations are Certified"       
                )
            );
```

App ID : 201571056616918

Please guide me what I have done wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Until your actions are approved you can't publish them to any users other than your app's official developer and test user accounts, nor can other users grant publish_actions permission to your app. To continue testing, specify or create your test users from the App administration interface